# Why the firstsection CSS class needs calc(100% - 70px) instead of calc(100% - 75px) to not have a scrolldown bar in CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning HTML and CSS.

I am currently facing an issue regarding the box model.

In the code below, regarding the firstsection CSS class, the value to not have a scrolldown bar on my window is calc(100% - 70px).

However, I do not understand this value as the minimal value to not have a scrolldown bar should be calc(100% - 75px) (the padding-top value).

Can you please explain me what is wrong with my thought ?

Thank you in advance.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
  margin: 8px;
}

.firstsection {
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-top: 75px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-bottom-style: ridge;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <section class="firstsection">
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element is overflowing the body by exactly `8px`.`3px` for the bottom border and `5px` for the remaining padding (`75px - 70px`). Since your body already have `8px` of margin bottom you will not trigger a scroll with your overflowing `8px` because they will sit on the top of the margin.

Add some coloration and transparency to better see the overflowing part at the bottom:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background:red;
}

body {
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
  margin: 8px;
  background:green;
  outline:1px solid yellow;
}

.firstsection {
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-top: 75px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-bottom-style: ridge;
  opacity:0.8;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <section class="firstsection">
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

If you add the overflow property to the body it will be trivial as you will trigger a scroll on the body:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background:red;
  overflow:auto;
}

body {
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
  margin: 8px;
  background:green;
  outline:1px solid yellow;
  overflow:auto;
}

.firstsection {
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-top: 75px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-bottom-style: ridge;
  opacity:0.8;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <section class="firstsection">
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And to avoid the scroll for the body you will need `calc(100% - 75px - 3px)` (all the padding and the border)

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background:red;
  overflow:auto;
}

body {
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
  margin: 8px;
  background:green;
  outline:1px solid yellow;
  overflow:auto;
}

.firstsection {
  height: calc(100% - 75px - 3px);
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-top: 75px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-bottom-style: ridge;
  opacity:0.8;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <section class="firstsection">
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```